# Is this function possible to create in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
fn foo(f: fn(u32) -> u32) -> fn(u32, u32) -> u32 {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

A function that takes a function pointer as an argument, and returns a function pointer that calls the original function, ignoring the extra parameter.

Something similar in concept to the following, ignoring that it doesn't compile:

```
fn foo(f: fn(u32) -> u32) -> fn(u32, u32) -> u32 {
    |x, _| f(x)
}
```

Comment: Whatever you return must call `f`, so it must remember `f` it has to call. Functions cannot remember anything, only closures can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  Functions do not have states, so each time you call `foo`, a brand new function has to be generated that calls `f` internally, which is apparently not possible.

If you are willing to relax the return type, you can return an `impl Fn(u32, u32) -> u32`:

```
fn foo(f: fn(u32) -> u32) -> impl Fn(u32, u32) -> u32 {
    move |x, _| f(x)
}

fn main() {
    let new_f = foo(|x| x);
    assert_eq!(new_f(1, 2), 1);
}
```